# Hoe do I translate version 2 to version 5 strategy in pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to figure out how to easily translate my v2 script to a v5 script.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have an EMA strategy that I coded on version 2 of pinescript, to have my bots automate my strategy, I need to translate the current version 2 script into the same script but translated into version 5 of pinescript.     Below is an example of a section of my v2 script, where do I look to learn this translation?                      
goLong() => crossover(fastMA, slowMA)
killLong() => crossunder(fastMA, slowMA)
strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, when = goLong())
strategy.close("Buy", when = killLong())

Answer (score 0):

First convert it to `v3` using [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_3.html) guide. Then you can use the auto-convert tool to upgrade it from `v3` to `v4` and then from `v4` to `v5`.

Comment: Thank you very much, will start working on this now!